# React: How to cover dynamic imports in Jest tests?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

so I have a react component that uses:

```
const MyPage = DynamicImport({
  id: 'MyPage',
  loader: () => import('./pages/MyPage/MyPageWrapper'),
});
```

and jest complains that my test isn't covering the loader, line 22:

[image]

then this is used later on the same file:

```
const tabs = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        label: 'myPage',
        url: 'myRoute',
        component: MyPage,
      },
      ...
```

and finally

```
{tabs.map(({ url, component }) => {
  return <Route path={url} component={component} key={url} />;
})}
```

I am learning how to write unit tests and I have no clue how to cover this piece in red lines on the screenshot, I've been obviously googling and searching for an answer but I couldn't find anything useful.

This is my test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { MyComponent } from '../MyComponent';
import { makeSetupComponent } from '../../../../test_utils';

const MyPage = () => ({
  id: '',
  loader: jest.fn(),
});

jest.mock('../pages/MyPage/MyPageWrapper', () => {
  return {
    MyPageWrapper: jest.fn(),
  };
});

const defaultProps = {
  ...
  };

const setup = makeSetupComponent({
  props: defaultProps,
  shallow: true,
  component: MyComponent,
});

describe('MyComponent component', () => {
  test('Renders correctly', () => {
    const { component } = setup();
    expect(component.exists()).toBe(true);
  });

  test('render MyPage', () => {
    const { component } = setup({ shallow: false });
    console.log('###DEBUG', component.debug());
    console.log('###MyPage', MyPage);

    const { loader } = MyPage();
    loader();

    expect(MyPage).toBeInstanceOf(Function);
    expect(loader).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Any help/suggestions/links/courses-that-cover-exactly-this would be highly appreciated

Comment: What's the test? Give a [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe I just edited the post adding my test file, this is my attempt but of course, this code doesn't cover the red lines that you can see on my screenshot, and that is my goal.

Comment: It's not clear why you expected otherwise; it looks like everything's mocked out, there's nothing left to test.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry, to be clear I want to increase coverage, if you check the screenshot in my post it says the line 22 isn't being covered and I am looking to cover it, so I am asking if someone know how to achieve it

Comment: Yes, that's clear. Have you tried testing the actual MyPage instead of the fake one you build in the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the unit test solution:

`DynamicImport.ts`:

```js
export async function DynamicImport({ id, loader }) {
  console.log('real implementation');
  return loader();
}
```

`MyPageWrapper.ts`

```js
export function MyPageWrapper() {
  return 'MyPageWrapper';
}
```

`index.ts`:

```js
import { DynamicImport } from './DynamicImport';

export function main() {
  return DynamicImport({
    id: 'MyPage',
    loader: () => import('./MyPageWrapper'),
  });
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { main } from './';
import { DynamicImport } from './DynamicImport';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';

jest.mock('./DynamicImport', () => {
  return {
    DynamicImport: jest.fn(),
  };
});

jest.mock('./MyPageWrapper', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: 'mocked MyPageWrapper',
}));

describe('62161452', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    mocked(DynamicImport).mockImplementationOnce(({ id, loader }) => {
      console.log('mocked implementation');
      return loader();
    });
    const actual = (await main()).default;
    expect(actual).toBe('mocked MyPageWrapper');
    expect(DynamicImport).toBeCalledWith({ id: 'MyPage', loader: expect.any(Function) });
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/62161452/index.test.ts (9.149s)
  62161452
    ✓ should pass (32ms)

  console.log
    mocked implementation

      at Object.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/62161452/index.test.ts:19:15)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.178s
```

test coverage html reporter:
[image]

Comment: this is wonderful! thank you! what would I use instead of the mocked() ? I don't have TS on my project, I don't think I can do this change atm

Comment: @WagnerMoreira Just remove `mocked` if you use JS. Others are same